# How to set dummy vagrant host name

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-provision

I want to test my web site by using a vagrant. My operating system is Mac and I use Ubuntu box. Each time vagrant starts, it sets `nodeproject-default-1467385921475-38104.shared` kind a entry in he host file. What is the proper way to set it so that when I type **mygreatapi.com** or **www.mygreatapi.com** it hits the vagrant box? I tried to use

`config.vm.hostname = "mygreatapi.com"`

but it sets hostname for box only. When I ping mygreatapi.com in the box, it pings to 127.0.0.1 but I can't reach mygreatapi.com from my Mac

Comment: vagrant will not do that by itself, you must use a specific plugin to handle host update such as vagrant-hostmanager or vagrant-hostsupdater or other so please complete your question with this information so we can give you an accurate answer, each plugin would use different settigns

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using private network and using manual entry in hosts file. If it gives me problem, I will try to use the plugins you mentioned.